# Is there a way to insert Google file location into Google Doc (Google Sheet, Google Slides)?

Tags: google-drive

I am looking for an easy way to keep track of/communicate Google file locations. When using the Google Drive links, these get a cryptic file_id. That works to get direct access to the document, but is tedious when file location is relevant information.

Ideally, I would want create links that include the pathway (i.e. foldernames).
Alternatively, a function could be built into a template, which would automatically insert the file location.

Has anyone resolved this? It does not seem like Google is offering this by default.., not sure why not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the path the first option is to add it manually as the link text. There is no built-in way to add the path link to the URL because Google Drive doesn't use conventional folders / directories to store files,

You could use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive) to get the file location the add this data somewhere. Let say that you are looking to add the file location to the link, this could done by adding the location to the [*query string*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) but you will have to use custom parameters.

Your script / program should some way update this parameters periodically as there isn't a trigger for file relocation.